# How can I remove a mark from a freshly painted wood cupboard?

Tags: painting, kitchens

While carrying a cupboard door to reinstall, my husband accidentally scratched a gray line on the door with his belt buckle. We were using ["Advance"-brand paint](http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-your-home/paint-products/advance-waterborne-interior-alkyd-paint).

How can I get this off without ruining the fresh paint?

Comment: Can't you just lightly sand the mark, wipe it with a damp, lint-free rag, and then touch-up paint?

Answer (score 6):

Touch the paint up with a tiny dab of paint and a small brush.  Paint takes about a month to cure, and little touch up jobs like this should blend right in by the time the paint finishes curing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a scuff, and not a deep scratch, [Magic Eraser](http://www.mrclean.com/en_US/magic-eraser.do) will surely get it off.  This thing does wonders, it should be part of everyone cleaning supplies.

Comment: I wouldn't do this to paint that hasn't fully cured though; the Magic Eraser will peel that paint right off. If this were a mark on six-month-old cabinets, definitely. In this situation I think touch-up is the better solution.

Comment: @KeithS good point.  Esp since the paint is available.